# Using terminal (ie, zsh), I want to run a certain shell command, every time, any file in a given folder is saved/added

Tags: terminal, command-line, automation, zsh

Hence, in a certain folder, say `~/Desktop/foo`,

any time a file/subfile/folder is touched (added, saved),

I want to just run a certain command in the shell.

Is there a way to do this, either with a zsh command, or perhaps some other automation on the Mac, or an app?? TY

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into macOS folder actions. This enables AppleScript and Automator actions to be setup to monitor a specific folder and act on changes.

The simplest way to run a shell script, is to use **Automator** with a `Run Shell Script` action. On startup, Automator will ask the type, `Folder Action` is the one to choose.

Some pointers:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WatchFolders.html

http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/folder-action/index.html

Be sure to checkout many other posts here on the subject also.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Folder Actions:

Ctrl-click any folder in the Finder and choose *Services>Folder Actions Setup* in Monterey.
In early versions of macOS, the option appears in the main lists of contextual items.

To avoid the malicious and accidental installation of Folder Actions, macOS requires a confirmation step that can’t be automated: click *Run Service* in the *Confirm Service* dialog.

This adds the current folder to the Folders with Actions list without adding actions.
The *Folder Actions Setup window* appears with a dialog already open that reads *Choose a Script to Attach*.

This list includes ones that Apple seeded, locating them inside the */Library/Scripts/Folder Actions Scripts* folder. Any scripts installed by apps or that you’ve created and placed inside your Home directory’s *~/Library/Scripts/Folder Actions Scripts* folder appear as well.

You can create Folder Actions in a numbers of ways:

- Use an item Apple provides in the dialog that appears when you invoke Folder Actions Setup. These mostly relate to image processing.
- Create a Folder Action in Automator using its broader set of tools. This can include passing information to an AppleScript, JavaScript, or shell script.
- Write your own AppleScript to perform a task.

Comment: superb answer (and nickname!)